# In-sample evaluation with different classifiers

Tags: classification, python, data-mining, scikit-learn, in-sample

I've tested **in-sample evaluation** with different classifiers (Decision trees, Random Forests, Gaussian Naive Bayes) within sklearn and Iris datasets.

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


iris=datasets.load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y=iris.target
```

> First with decision trees, I get 100% accuracy

```
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(df,y)
print(str(clf.score(df, y)))
```

> For other classifiers, the score is strictly lower than 100%

For example within Random forests I have:

```
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(df,y)
print(str(clf.score(df, y)))
```

In [47]: 0.96

With RandomForestClassifier, the score is 98%. It's also the case with other classifiers such as KNeighbors.

My question:

**Is there a theoretical reason for which decision trees give a 100% accuracy score for in-sample evaluations, and why the other classifiers do not ?
In other words, is there a case where decision trees can have an accuracy score strictly lower than 100% for in-sample evaluation ?**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no theoretical reason, only a practical one. Any method can achieve an in-sample accuracy of 100%. It's easy, just make it overfit. Of course, the out-sample accuracy may crash.

This is why the in-sample accuracy score is not used on its own, but with the out-sample score as well, to be able to check that the model is not overfitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For sure, the out-sample accuracy will not be good, that was not really my point. Actually, the question is rather why for decision trees, the in-sample accuracy is always 100%, without making any change on the data (I did not try to overfit, and it gives 100% accuracy for all data sets)

Comment: You can always get up to 100%. For decision trees, it may be that for your dataset, the default hyper parameters make them overfit.

Comment: my data set has no particular feature, here I test with the Iris data. You can try with any other data set. the result will be the same : 100% for decision trees, and a score strictly lower than 100% for other methods. There should be a reason I guess?

Comment: hyperparameters, that's all. You can make the other datasets overfit as well. Just increase their capacity.

Comment: You mean other methods right? Ok, based on the same Iris data set : are you able to provide a code in which Gaussian NB gives 100% for in-sample evaluation OR a code that gives less than 100% for decision trees?

Comment: Change the hyperparameters, use a shallower tree, not sure is Gaussian NB in sklearn have parameters than can make it overfit, haven't seen hyper parameters there.